# Primary key vs Key index speed

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table with 2K registers `InnoDB` engine. The first two fields be a `PRIMARY KEY (AUTO INCREMENT)` called `id` and a `INDEX KEY VARCHAR(255)` called `codreg`.

Before my table only had a `PRIMARY KEY (VARCHAR(6))` called `codreg`.

The problem is with the new config, the searches by codreg (like) are slower than the only codreg configuration.

Are the primary key indexes faster than the key index?

This question is related to performance issues I'm having to do this query

```
SELECT CE.*, GI.* FROM ($_q_aux) CE inner join table2 GI ON GI.codreg=CE.codreg
```

$_q_aux is:

```
SELECT codreg FROM table2 WHERE codreg like '%string%'
```

table 1 is 2k entries and table2 20K entries

The time of execution is too slowly..

Comment: Thanks for the edit, someone can i help me?

Comment: Even though you didn't say which engine you use, the answer is - yes, PK is "faster" than normal index. Also, `LIKE` searches are extremely ineffective and it's questionable how you executed it (whether it's efficient or not), plus having a varchar for PK most likely won't yield the best performance. You can optimize your searches to be way, way faster. Even without indexes. 2k entries is a drop in the sea for MySQL.

Comment: InnoDb is the engine. actually the PK is a AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: Then increase your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a larger value and measure the performance again. Google what it does first though. And read what Nikola said about using LIKE searches.

Comment: Added new info to the original question

Comment: Like Nikola told you already, using `LIKE '%string%'` is slow and index won't be used. However, doing `LIKE 'string%'` CAN use the index. Use `EXPLAIN` to profile your query and optimize your MySQL settings.

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same thing. But you real problem is that you use varchar for PK - why ?
You should use some of the integer types like INT and you will see realy great performance improvement.

If you really need to have such a column varchar then first check if you know the exact length of the field if you know it , then you should use the char(6).

Also keep in mind that when you do LIKE search if you put the "%" ONLY on last position, your searches will be faster, otherwise they will scan every row. So if you can use WHERE codreg like "123%", and not "%123%"

Comment: You're mixing valid and invalid advices, which is why I didn't downvote or upvote you. But the main thing where you're wrong is saying that "they are basically the same thing". Yes, indexing a number or a string boils down to the same thing deep, deep down. But, the difference is with how the index structure is organized physically (in InnoDB and TokuDB). And that's where the difference lies and why PK nearly always yields greater speed compared to other type of indexes (if they're nonclustered).

Comment: added new info to the original question

Comment: I've tried to use 'string%' and the performance does not improve. If try to do a query only "SELECT codreg FROM table2 WHERE codreg like '%string%'" the performance is good but the problem is when I do the query "SELECT CE.*, GI.* FROM ($_q_aux) CE inner join table2 GI ON GI.codreg=CE.codreg" ...Any idea about to solve it? thanks